# How to add external Javascript in a laravel view

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to add my javascript file externally in my login view. I have given the js src link on my layouts/app.blade.php at the end of the body and in the head too. I tried to give the js link my view but it does not work. The script only works when i place it internally in my login view.

Login.blade.php

```
<script>
//internal script
   $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("this is alert");
        $(".btn-gSignIn").mouseenter(function(){
            $(".btn-gSignIn").animate({background-color: white , color:#4285F4 , border-radius: 0px},5000);
            $(".btn-gSignIn").animate({background-color: #F3F3F3 , color:black , border-radius: 20px},5000);
        });
        $("div").css("background-color", "grey");

    });

</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="{{ asset('js/login.js') }}" ></script>
```

app.blade.php

```
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')

        </main>
    </div>

</body>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="{{ asset('js/login.js') }}" ></script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `type="text/babel"`?

Comment: If i do javascript it gives an syntax error Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you login.blade.php, after `@endsection` place your js import in push stack:

```
@push('js')
<script src="{{ asset('js/login.js') }}" ></script>
@endpush
```

In your app.blade.php, place your js files just before your `</body>` tag ends.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"</script> 
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
@stack('js')
</body>
```

also if you're using default app.js that ships with laravel, then it can cause conflict with jquery.

Comment: i want to add it externally not in the login.blade.php it works fine internally. i have a login.js file which have the script in public/js folder

Comment: Externally as in a .js file?

Comment: the script in a js file and it should link with my view

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your js console and make sure your login.js doesn't contain any `<script>` tags, you also wanna remove `type="text/babel"`.

Comment: Thanks i was using <script> tags in my login.js that solved it